# Space and time complexity of 2M multiplication method

Tags: binary, time-complexity, fpga, multiplication, space-complexity

Have anyone used this [2M multiplication method](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/415c/d98dafb5c9cb358c94189927e1f3216b7494.pdf#page=10) ?

> By trading a small factor of logN in the asymptotic area, the following algorithm gives a feasible and nicely regular silicon layout

1. How does the increase of logN in area complexity resulted in regular layout ?
2. Besides, adding those '2' (or two '1's in binary, just imagine putting 1'b1 on top of each other vertically) by itself also requires carry-save adders which may also contribute to the overall latency or delay as well as resulted in irregular layout ?

[image: 2M multiplication block diagram]

[image: actual numerical example]